# How UnitOfWork patterns helps to resolve concurrent issues?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, unit-of-work

I've read about **Unit of Work** enterprise design pattern from Martin Fowler's famous book and I have several questions:

Author says that this pattern need to :
1. Avoid redundant database communications(it's clear)
2. Solve concurrent issues

### Questions:

1. Actually I didn't get how this pattern can help to solve concurrent issues. Could you explain it?
2. Should I create UoW instance for each entity class or for each entity object or singleton instance per application?

In one example from book UoW looks like this:

```
class UnitOfWork ....

    private List newObjects = new ArrayList();
    private List dirtyObjects = new ArrayList();
    private List removedObjects = new ArrayList();


    public void registerNew(DomainObject o){...}
    public void registerDirty(DomainObject o){...}
    public void registerRemoved(DomainObject o){...}
    public void registerClean(DomainObject o){...}
```

Here looks like single UoW is responsible for some set of objects

But in another example :

```
class UnitOfWorkServlet ...
   final protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
      try{
         UnitOfWork.newCurrent(); // create UnitOfWorkInstance in ThreadLocal
         handleGet(request, response);
         UnitOfWork.getCurrent().commit() 
      } finally(){
         UnitOfWork.setCurrent(null) //threadLocalInstance.set(null)
      }
   }
```

Here we create new UoW instance per each Get request and look like each request isolated from  another one. How can it solve concurrent isssues ?

Lets say we have 2 related entities: Client and Order. Should we create 2 different UnitOfWork instances or should we use the single instance fir both entities?

---

Author states that we have to store UoF instance in ThreadLocal to avoid disaster but I didn't get why. What is he speaking about ?

Let's say we have 2 different simultaneous requests from UI but both of them update the Client fieds in database. could you explain the behaviour of such requests? How many UoF works should be created and how they fix concurrent issues ?

### P.S.

I mostly experience in java so it is ok for me if your answers will explain things based on JPA/Hibernate